# Eliminating "contained" solution subsets for Solve[]

Tags: equation-solving

Here are the first two lines of a `Solve[]` that went through in a few seconds (yay, Mathematica, I more expected three days due to the system being highly nonlinear with 10 variables):

```
{       {b1->0,c1->0,c2->0,d1->0},
{a1->-b2,b1->0,c1->0,c2->0,d1->0},...}
```

Must be `a1+b2` in a Groebner or whatnot, but evidently solution 2 is just a more specific instance of solution 1, and if I could automatically eliminate all those instances, the solution set will get more handy than 309 possibilities :-)

Can I? If yes, I haven't the slightest idea yet how to. (OK, `MaxExtraConditions` brings it down to 239, which happens to be my favorite integer...but the first two remain.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "those instances" means getting rid of "solution 2", this works on the OP's MWE:

```
{{b1 -> 0, c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, d1 -> 0},
 {a1 -> -b2, b1 -> 0, c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, d1 -> 0}
 } /. Rule -> Equal //
    Apply[Or] //
   Apply[And, #, {1}] & // (* first three lines convert to equations *)
  LogicalExpand //         (* eliminates logically redundant ones *)
 Solve

(*  {{b1 -> 0, c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, d1 -> 0}}  *)
```

Comment: Looks good! I entered a test system `Solve[{b + c == 3, b*c == 2, a*(b - 2*c)*(c - 2*b) == 0}]` (which gives 2 solutions for `b,c` and two superfluous with additional `a=0`) and your code eliminated all latter, i.e. it seems to work on an arbitrary large system. Approved.